# How can I use the return from a axios http request in nest js

Tags: axios, rxjs, nest

[this return an Observable, and i want to iterate over the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iep8L.png)

how can I do that?

Comment: Show us your code, as text, not image please. Try to create a minimum example. Then show us what you expect, what you tried and what is not working as expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for something which is very well documented. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I found the error, It was that the api was returning the data as string, I was just have to Parse the data and It work.\

Answer (score 0):

I used `firstDataValue` instead of PiPe.

So the error was that the API was sending me back the data as a string, and I wanted the iterate over the result and I couldn't. So I use `JSON.parse(data)`.

The result was:

```
let data=firstValueFrom(await this.httpService.get("url")).data;
let dataParsed=JSON.Parse(data);//this was the error cause the api was sending strign
return dataParsed[0]
```